# call to super first line

Tags: java

I am a newbee so advise and help is always greatly appreciated.

Cannot seem to get my container contentPane to display the title.

My code:

```
class CreateStockCodeDetails extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{ 

     OptraderSA parent; 


     OptraderGlobalParameters GV = new OptraderGlobalParameters(); 
     private boolean DEBUG = true; //Set DEBUG = true for Debugging 

JButton SAVE_BUTTON     = new JButton("SAVE"); 
JButton CANCEL_BUTTON   = new JButton("CANCEL"); 

Font MyFont         = new Font("Helvetica",Font.BOLD,24); 

JLabel PriceBidLabel           = new JLabel("  Bid Price",JLabel.LEFT); 
JLabel PriceAskLabel           = new JLabel("  Ask Price",JLabel.LEFT); 
JLabel PriceMidLabel           = new JLabel("  Mid Price",JLabel.LEFT); 
JLabel DividendLabel           = new JLabel("  Dividend",JLabel.LEFT); 

JTextField PriceBid    = new JTextField(5); 
JTextField PriceAsk    = new JTextField(5); 
JTextField PriceMid    = new JTextField(5); 
JTextField Dividend           = new JTextField(5); 

JTextField NewUnderlyingCode  = new JTextField(10); 

String NewCode; 

 public void CreateStockDetails(String StockCode) 
 { 
       **super("Hallo All");** 

       Container contentPane = getContentPane(); 
       setSize(400,500); 
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 

       //Centre Screen To Right Of Main 
  Dimension sd=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); 
  super.setLocation(sd.width/2-100/2, sd.height/2-300/2);
```

Thanks

Kind Regards Stephen

Comment: There's no question here. What's your problem? What are you seeing? What are you expecting?

Comment: You might want to format your code better. It's hard to read and harder to cut & paste to try it out...

Comment: More to the point, his constructor isn't - don't use `void`

Comment: did you solve it? If you still have problems, I could help you further if you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

First, note that you can only call `super("Hallo All")` in your constructor.

As I see it you have two problems:

1. A constructor has **no return type**. Thus remove `void`
2. The constructor must have the **same name as the class**.

That is, change from

```
 public void CreateStockDetails(String StockCode) 
 { 
       **super("Hallo All");**
```

to this

```
 public CreateStockCodeDetails(String StockCode) 
 { 
       super("Hallo All");
```

Also, as a side-note: According to Java conventions, you should use lower case initial letters for variable identifiers, that is, write `stockCode` instead of `StockCode` and you should not have a new-line before opening braces.

Comment: StackOverflow highlights what it thinks of as a class, too, using camel-case conventions, which emphasizes your point.

Comment: His class is named CreateStockCodeDetails so he should also change the name of the "constructor". And according to Java conventions, it is not a good idea to give a class such a name anyway. StockDetailsCreator would be more appropriate.

Comment: I wish I knew what you are talking about why is StockDetailsCreator  better?????????

Comment: Prefer nouns over verbs for class names. (The important part however is that the constructor should not have a return type (`void`) and it should have the same name as the class.)